# Can you change location of testng-results.xml for each job in Jenkins

Tags: java, maven, selenium, jenkins, selenium-webdriver

Is there a way to change the location for each job in Jenkins? I have a lot of Maven projects/jobs in Jenkins and I would like each job to have its own location for the testng-results.xml file. Can this be done?

I'm using Selenium WebDriver, coding in Java, using TestNG (obviously) and the project managed by Maven.

Currently all of the jobs executed by Jenkins write to the same testng-results.xml file in the target\surefire-reports directory.

Answer (score 0):

Add a maven step to the wanted job, with the following command after the report was generated:

```
mvn surefire-report:report -DoutputDirectory=newpath
```

Comment: Would I do this in the way of "Add post-build step" and doing "Invoke top-level Maven targets"? When I do that, it tries to execute another test from my pom.xml

Comment: In that case, try adding the -DoutputDirectory argument to the command that runs your build and tests.

Comment: Doing that, the test runs fine, but nothing changes with the output. It just keeps being written to the default path